# Unable to send push notification from FCM Admin (NodeJS) everywhen server restart

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, web-push

I've setup a NodeJS server-side app , integrated with Firebase Admin NodeJS SDK. Client-side (Javascript) can be able to receive push notifications after the following steps:

1. Client-side receive **registration token** after registrated ServiceWorker, `requestPermission()` then `getToken()`, then send it to server-side
2. Server-side store received **registration token** into DB.
3. Server-side send a dummy welcome message to that **registration token** using Firebase Admin NodeJS SDK. Google Chrome received push notification successfully.

Now, restart server-side (`forever restart bin/www`, etc...)

4. **PROBLEM 1 HERE**: I send a dummy message from server-side again. Nothing happened in GG Chrome.
5. **PROBLEM 2 HERE**: Repeat step 1, and I got **totally new registration token**. An old becomes useless.

I've read through many pages of [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/admin/send-messages) but sill have no idea how to solve that problem.

My code at step 1:

```
const self = this;
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  if (!firebase.apps.length)
    firebase.initializeApp({
      apiKey: "AIzaSyDu888R1nyP_W_xFX7aATSB0U5irf79lrM",
      authDomain: "hungphongbk-1812.firebaseapp.com",
      databaseURL: "https://hungphongbk-1812.firebaseio.com",
      projectId: "hungphongbk-1812",
      storageBucket: "hungphongbk-1812.appspot.com",
      messagingSenderId: "1926697148"
    });
  const messaging = firebase.messaging();
  messaging.onMessage(function (payload) {
    console.log("Message received. ", payload);
    const {notification} = payload;
    new Notification(notification.title, {
      body: notification.body
    });
  });
  // window.addEventListener('load', async () => {
  (async function () {
    try {
      const registration = await navigator.serviceWorker.register('/sw.js')
      messaging.useServiceWorker(registration);
      await messaging.requestPermission();
      const token = await messaging.getToken();
      console.log(token);
      self.token = token;
      await post('/noti/register', {token});
    } catch (e) {
      alert(e.message);
    }
  })()
}
```